# How to terminate processes in a bash file? (.sh)

Tags: bash

I am running a java TCP/IP server/client set up, and need to automate multiple instances of the client in a bash file like so:

```
javac *.java
java Server1 &

java Client &
java Client &
java Client &
java Client &
java Client &
ETC.
```

How do I get them all to terminate when complete?

Comment: It's only a bash script if it starts with `#!/bin/bash`. If it starts with `#!/bin/sh`, it's a POSIX sh script. The extension isn't enough to say anything useful about the type -- you could have a file named with a `.sh` extension but starting with `#!/usr/bin/env python` and it'd be a Python script; indeed, it's better practice not to use filename extensions on executables at all (notice how you run `ls`, not `ls.elf`?)

Comment: What Charles said.  Another way of thinking of this is that in Unix and Linux, there's no such thing as "extensions". Those are a hold-over from obsolete operating systems like DOS, and while some modern applications understand the concept of a suffix on a filename indicating its type, that's really just for compatibility with folks who are still thinking in DOS terms. Ever notice that you can load a PNG file into an image editor even if you rename it to have a .GIF extension?  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want proper, safe job control, you need to keep track of the process IDs of the backgrounded applications as you background them.

Instead of relying on the output of `ps`, you should consider using something like this as a start/stop script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

numclients=5

case "$1" in

  start)
    # Start the server first...
    java Server1 &
    pid=$!
    echo "$pid" > /var/run/Server1.pid

    # Then start the clients.
    for clid in $(seq 1 $numclients); do
      java client &
      pid=$!
      echo "$pid" > /var/run/client-${clid}.pid
    done
    ;;

  stop)
    # Kill the clients first
    for clid in $(seq 1 $numclients); do
      if [ -s /var/run/client-${clid}.pid ]; then
        kill -TERM $(< /var/run/client-${clid}.pid)
      fi
    done

    # Then, kill the server
    if [ -s /var/run/Server1.pid ]; then
      kill -TERM $(< /var/run/Server1.pid)
    fi
    ;;

esac
```

I just wrote this, I haven't tested it. If there are typos or incompatibilities with your environment, feel free to solve them and consider the script above script an *example* of what you should do.

Note that in particular, the `seq` command is available in FreeBSD and many Linux distros, but is not in older versions of OSX. There are easy alternatives if you need them.  `jot` can function as a replacement in OSX or FreeBSD, and if you don't need/want to use the `$numclients` variable, you could make a "sequence expression" by using `{1..5}` (or whatever) instead.

Also, there are a number of other factors you might want to consider when launching and killing your application.  For example:

- What should happen if everything is already running?
- What should happen if only the server or only the clients are already running?
- What should happen if the wrong number of clients are already running?
- What happens if clients (or even the server) die?  (Hint: look at tools like [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html).)
- What happens if pid files are stale?

All of these conditions may be covered by tools that your operating system already uses. You might want to look in to building your application startup and teardown scripts using your system scripts as examples.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all Linux and OS X machines have `pkill`, which accepts a string and will kill the process of the same name.

Comment: And that's not safe for script use at all, unless if you restrict the group.

Comment: It also subjects the system to the exact same risks that the `ps | grep | grep` solution does.  If you're running a server, treat it like a server.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `kill` and pass in a list of `pid`s from `grep` like so:

```
kill `ps -ef | grep 'java Client' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $3}'`
```

Comment: Would I need to replicate that line for each instance of Client?

Comment: No, all process IDs matching the grep will be killed.

Comment: It seems to be working, the port is no longer in use, any idea how i can get rid of this error?    kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
./BashPart2.sh: line 24: kill: (501) - No such process
Terminated: 15

Comment: I forgot the `awk '{print $3}'` part.  Try adding it after the `grep -v grep` so it only uses the `pid` and not the whole line matched by the grep.

Comment: A nice way to avoid having grep find itself is `grep 'java Clien[t]'`

Comment: What if you have other java clients running?  A far better approach would be to actually keep track of what gets launched, then kill only the processes you know need to be killed.  See my answer for an example of a start/stop script that does this.

Comment: Also "grep | grep | awk" is a bit redundant. There is almost nothing that grep can do that awk can't also do.  `ps -aopid,cmd | awk 'NF>1 && /java client/&&$0!~/grep/{print $1}` would  replace this string of pipes, though it would do just as bad a job in terms of matching similarly named processes that you might not want to kill.